# Groebner basis over rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, computational-algebra, groebner-basis

Let $I$ be an ideal in $A[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, where $A$ is a Noetherian commutative ring, such that w.r.t. some monomial order it has a Groebner basis $G = \{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}$ with all the leading coefficients of each $g_i$ equal to $1$. For $S \subseteq \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ it is given an $f \in A[S] \cap I$. Can we then assume that we always can choose $f'\in A[S] \cap I$ such that the leading coefficient of $f'$ is $1$?

Comment: The usual definition of Grobner basis requires $A$ to be a field. Can you explain what you mean by Grobner basis in you question? Additionally, it would be helpful if you are more precise about the meaning of the phrase "Can we assume".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to assume that $A$ is a domain.
Otherwise the answer is **no**.

Assume there are elements $a,b \in A \setminus \{0\}$ with $ab =0$.
Consider the ring $A[x_1,x_2]$ with the lexicographic order in which $x_1 > x_2$.
Furthermore, consider the ideal $I = (x_1 - a x_2)$.
The generator $x_1 - a x_2$ is a Grobner basis of this ideal.

One can easily compute the quotient ring:
$$A[x_1,x_2] /I \simeq A[x_2], \quad x_1 \mapsto a x_2, x_2 \mapsto x_2.$$

Hence
$$I \cap A[x_1] = \operatorname{ker}( A[x_1] \to A[x_1,x_2] \to A[x_2] )$$ 
with the map
$$A[x_1] \to A[x_2], \quad x_1 \mapsto a x_2 .$$

Thus $I \cap A[x_1]$ cannot contain monic polynomials.
But $bx_1 = b (x_1 - ax_2) \in I \cap A[x_1]$.